# @Aspectj based AOP : Advice is not getting called

Tags: java, spring, aop

Read the related queries here, but none of them were help ful.

This is my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="advice1" class="Aspects.Advice"></bean>

<bean id="module1" class="objects.Modules">
<constructor-arg index="0"> <ref bean="resource1"/> </constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="1" value="10 Oct"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="2" value="11 Oct"></constructor-arg>

<property name="moduleName" value="SaleLayaway"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="resource1" class="objects.Resource">
<property name="name" value="Smruti"></property>
<property name="designation" value="PA"></property>
<property name="teamName" value="BackEnd"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

This is my Aspect :

```
package Aspects;

 @Aspect
public class Advice {


@Pointcut("execution(public void Modules.displayModule*.*(..))")
public void pointCut1()//point cut name
{

}

@Before("pointCut1()")
public void inputLogger(JoinPoint jp)
{
    System.out.println(" inside advice");
    System.out.println("We are gonna start service signature         :"+jp.getSignature());
    System.out.println("Target name: "+jp.getTarget());
}


  }
```

This is my main "Modules" having "displayModuleInfo" method where I need to add the advice:

```
package objects;

 public class Modules {


private Resource rescource;
private String startDate;
private String finsihDate;
private String moduleName;


public String getModuleName() {
    return moduleName;
}

public void setModuleName(String moduleName) {
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
}

public Modules(Resource rescource, String startDate, String finsihDate) {
    super();
    this.rescource = rescource;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.finsihDate = finsihDate;

}
public Modules(){

}
/*@Autowired
public Modules(Resource rescource) {
    super();
    this.rescource = rescource;
}*/

public void displayModuleInfo(){
    System.out.println(" module name: "+moduleName);
    System.out.println(" Resource name : "+rescource.getName()+":Designation :"+rescource.getDesignation()+" : team name :"+rescource.getTeamName());
    System.out.println(" module start date :"+startDate+" : finish date : "+finsihDate);
}

  }
```

I am not able to identify why advices are not working. This is the o/p i am getting

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger         (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
  module name: SaleLayaway
   Resource name : Smruti:Designation :PA : team name :BackEnd
   module start date :10 Oct : finish date : 11 Oct
```

I have these added these jars for AOP:
[image]

Whats the obvious thing I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pointcut declaration seems to be malformed. I created a sample app and it seems that it should be :

```
@Pointcut("execution(public void objects.Modules.displayModule*(..))")
public void pointCut1()//point cut name
{

}
```

This declaration matches any method, where name starts with `displayModule` declared by the `objects.Modules` class. IIRC your declaration would match any method, declared by a class which name starts with `displayModule` residing in the `Modules` package.

In case you missed it, the [reference has great examples on how to create pointcuts](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples).

Comment: Oh My bad ..How could I miss it... objects.Modules.. I wasnt using package name.. Its working fn now..Thanks Man

Comment: The `objects.Modules` needs to be the fully qualified name of the class. I based it on the `package` shown in your example.